# PRE ANSI-92 Left Join Syntax (Sybase)

Tags: sql-server, sybase, left-join

What is the syntax to specify a Left Join using pre ANSI-92 syntax (i.e. *=) when part of the Where clause has an 'equal to some constant' condition ? (in this case 100 is the constant)

Example:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t.* 
FROM (select * from SybaseTable where ID=1) t, SqlServerTable t1
WHERE t1.ID *= 100 and t1.SeqNo *= t.SeqNo
```

In this case I want all records from derived table 't', even if 't1' has no match. I want t1.ID to return NULL in the Select clause when a matching row on SeqNo does not exist in 't'.

The error I am receiving is "Both terms of an outer join must contain columns".

I am executing this query in SQL Server 2005 for now, but it will eventually be used against a Sybase implementation, which requires the old join syntax.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it, but you'll have to test to be certain:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t.* 
FROM (select * from SybaseTable where ID=1) t, SqlServerTable t1
WHERE t.SeqNo *= t1.SeqNo AND 100 *= t1.ID
```

Notice that I reversed the order on the SeqNo part, to better indicated which is the left side of the join.

Comment: I tried that and it returns no records,  it does not behave like a Left Join when *= is removed from the "= 100" part

Comment: Hmm... try the 100 on the left side of the *=

Comment: Or perhaps a case condition: when t1.ID = 100 then t1.ID ELSE null

Comment: cool....the reversal of the SeqNo part was my mistake. That was causing the problem all along.